# git diff --name-only and SHA

Tags: git

I need to run git diff between two commits and the result should be files introduced with the corresponding SHA.

Currently I can do:

```
git diff --name-only [start-sha] [end-sha]
```

which gives:

```
myfolder/a.txt
code/snippet.c
test.txt
```

But how do I get the SHA for when each of those files where modified/added so the resulting output becomes:

```
myfolder/a.txt     2314d344
code/snippet.c     gfhr76kl
test.txt           jk5534bf
```

?

Figure I could just do:

```
$files = git diff --name-only [start-sha] [end-sha]
foreach ($f in $files) {
     $sha = git log -n1 --format=format:%H $f
     print $f $sha
}
```

so getting the last commit/SHA where the file $f was modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is an internal git command to do this, but you could always just loop over your files and grab the first commit:

```
for file in `git diff [start-sha] [end-sha] --name-only`; 
    do echo -n "$file "; git log --pretty=short [start-sha] [end-sha] -- $file | /bin/grep commit | cut -b8- | head -n 1;
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question conceals a fundamental issue.  Let's take a look at a typical commit graph fragment:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I--J  <-- master
```

You pick two commits, such as `E` and `I`, and run `git diff --name-only` (or `git diff --name-status`) to compare them:

> ```
> $ git diff --name-only <hash-E> <hash-I>
> myfolder/a.txt
> code/snippet.c
> test.txt
> ```

but then say:

> ... the result should be files introduced with **the** corresponding SHA.

The fact that these file names come out means that all three files are present in commits `E` and/or `I`, but if you had commit `E` in your work-tree and wanted to modify it to get commit `I`, those three files would need some kind of change: create, modify, or even delete.  Using `--name-status` will give you the *kind* of change as well: `A` for "the file is to be newly created", `M` for "the file is to be modified", and `D` for "the file is to be deleted".  (There are, of course, probably dozens or thousands of files in both `E` and `I` that are *the same* and hence are not printed here.)

But now you ask for *the* corresponding hash where this change is introduced.  There may not be a *the* hash.  There might be *more than one*.  (There must be *at least* one of course).  For instance, `test.txt` might be removed entirely in `F` by mistake (instead of being corrected), put back intact-but-wrong in `H`, and then corrected in `I`.  Meanwhile `code/snippet.c` might be modified in both `G` *and* `I`.

Which commit hash(es) would you like for each file?  The answer to *that* determines how to find them.  (Of course, if there is only one such hash, the problem vanishes.)

[xxfelixxx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972453/1256452) gives a (slighlty faulty but easily fixed and improved) method for obtaining one commit—the first one `git log` prints.  To fix the one bug and improve it a bit, replace the `do` sequence with:

```
do echo -n "$file "; git rev-list <starthash>..<endhash> -- "$file" | head -1
```

That is, we want to find one of the commit hashes printed by `git rev-list` when run only over the specified start/stop points *and* looking for changes to the one file.  We need `<starthash>..<endhash>` to do the initial commit-limiting, and the `-- $file` to select only commits that add, modify, or remove that one path.  Note that if there are spaces in the file name you will need to quote it (so I did), although then reading the output of `git diff` itself gets tricky too.

Using `head -1` gets you the *most recent* commit that touched the file, e.g., with our example where `code/snippet.c` in both `G` and `I`, you get the hash for commit `I`.  This is because Git works backwards, from newer commits to older ones.  If you want the *first* one, use `tail -1`, and if you want all of them, you will need a fancier format. :-)

(There is another subtle difference here, between `git log` and `git rev-list`, involving merge commits, but that probably won't affect you.)